# Cordova 10 not connect to http

Tags: android, cordova, authorization

My app is built with Cordova 10. I added platform Android.
It calls Web service SOAP. But it's not connect to the web server.
I tried few tests such as add an iframe including a https url. It works fine.
But nothing display with an in an iframe including a http url.
I think my app refuses http. This what i have in my config.xml.
As you can see, i allow everything. What's wrong ?

```
<widget id=....
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Android version of devices where this did not work? Does https work?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to use clear text traffic, see

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-enable-cleartext-traffic

But depending on what you're trying to do, as the webview is now served using https, it might reject loading resources over http.

Comment: The point is I try to call a SOAP web service. 
The app worked fine in older version of Cordova.
It fails to connect on Cordova 10.
I included an iframe with an url http just to confirm there's something wrong with the connection. The plugin fails

Comment: Like my answer stated, you can't mix https and http calls from a https webview. You might need to deploy SSL on the SOAP host or use another host to do the proxy

Comment: i don't understand why it worked on older version of Cordova and not in Cordova 10.x whereas i didn't change anything. The host, the code, the calls are always the same.

Comment: Cordova changed, the webview is now served via https only